# How many RADs are actually lethal?

Tags: radiation

**How many RADs are actually lethal?**

How many RADs (Radiation Absorbed Dose) per hour are lethal? Google says [Doses of 200 to 1,000 rad delivered in a few hours will cause serious illness with poor outlook at the upper end of the range.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rad_(unit)) however that's not very specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lethality of radiation varies with the type of radiation, area of the body exposed, the intensity of exposure to a particular location, and access to medical care

However, the [US Nuclear Regulatory Commission](https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/basic-ref/glossary/lethal-dose-ld.html) provides an estimate of the LD50/30, defined as:

> The dose of radiation expected to cause death to 50 percent of an exposed population within 30 days

The LD50/30 is:

> Typically... in the range from 400 to 450 rem

For X-rays and gamma rays, rad and rem are approximately equivalent. For other types of radiation, use the following [approximations](https://news.mit.edu/2011/explained-radioactivity-0328):

| Type | Rad | Rem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X-rays | 1 | 1 |
| Gamma rays | 1 | 1 |
| Neutrons | 1 | 5-20 |
| Alpha | 1 | 20 |

In [a review of individuals exposed accidentally to ionizing radiation and who received modern medical care](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5941165/), the vast majority of individuals exposed to more than 600 rad expired within 1 year.